# problem in Xcode playground with SwiftUI , Xcode 12.4

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcplayground

The live view shows a tiny box that just fits the text or whatever inside the view it doesn't show a full phone

here is the code

```
@State private var favoriteColor = "Red"
var colors = ["Red", "Green", "Blue"]

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        Picker(selection: $favoriteColor, label: Text("hey")) {
                Text("hey2")
        }
        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        Text("\(favoriteColor)")
    }
}
```

[here is how the live view looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJQ1s.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your attached image, you show some code that you didn't actually include in your question. In it, you initialize a `UIHostingController` with a certain size, but then never do anything with it -- instead, you set the playground view to just `ContentView`.

You can make the `ContentView` appear with a larger frame by adding a `frame` modifier to it:

```
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView().frame(width: 375, height: 667))
```